# N-Repeated Element in Size 2N Array

Tags: java

In an array A of size `2N`, there are `N+1` unique elements, and exactly one of these elements is repeated `N` times.

Return the element repeated `N` times.

I am trying to solve this algorithm but I can't seem to figure out why my count keeps getting reset. Any inputs will really be appreciated.

```
public class RepeatedElementInSize2NArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArr = new int[] {1,2,3,3};
        int repeatedElement = findRepeatedElement(inputArr);
        System.out.println("Repeated element : "+repeatedElement);

    }

    public static int findRepeatedElement(int[] inputArr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> repeatedElementMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
            if (repeatedElementMap.containsKey(inputArr[i])) {
                count = repeatedElementMap.get(inputArr[i]);
                repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count++);
            } else {
                repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], 1);
            }
        }
        int length = inputArr.length;
        int repeatedElement = 0;
        if (repeatedElementMap.containsValue(length % 2)) {
            repeatedElement = repeatedElementMap.get(length % 2);
        }
        return repeatedElement;

    }

}
```

Comment: What precisely do you expect to happen when executing this code, and what happens instead? Why do you compute the value length % 2? It's guaranteed to be 0 since length is 2N, and 2N is a multiple of 2

Comment: @azurefrog or better: count + 1

Answer (score 1):

It should be `++count` instead of `count++` in the line `repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count++);`
The reason is that the latter returns the value of count first before incrementing the value, whereas the former increments the value first and then returns it.

Comment: It should actually be count + 1. There is no reason to increment count (which, BTW, should be a local to the if block).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line `repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count++);`

The expression `count++` will increment the value of count, but **return the old value of count**.

So the code `repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count++);` could also be written like this:

```
repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count);
count += 1;
```

The effect would be the same, but in the second code you clearly see that there is a problem.

**Solution**:

Replace the line like this: `repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count + 1);`

**Edit**

Like azurefrog mentioned in the comments there is another problem in the lookup of the repeated element:

In the last if statement you search for a containing value, and if the value is found you try to get the element. But the get method searchs for a key, not a value. Also I don't realy get why you use modulo 2 instead of just dividing by 2. A better way would be to just run through the entries and search for one that has the searched number of elements like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : repeatedElementMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() == length / 2) {
        repeatedElement = entry.getKey();
    }
}
```

So the complete working code would look like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 3};
        int repeatedElement = findRepeatedElement(inputArr);
        System.out.println("Repeated element : " + repeatedElement);

    }

    public static int findRepeatedElement(int[] inputArr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> repeatedElementMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
            if (repeatedElementMap.containsKey(inputArr[i])) {
                count = repeatedElementMap.get(inputArr[i]);
                repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count+1);
            }
            else {
                repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], 1);
            }
        }
        int length = inputArr.length;
        int repeatedElement = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : repeatedElementMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == length / 2) {
                repeatedElement = entry.getKey();
            }
        }

        return repeatedElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it won't because his lookup logic is also broken.

Answer (score 0):

`count++` is a post-increment, meaning the value you insert to the hashmap is the value of `count`, and then `count` is incremented.

`++count` is a pre-increment. The value you insert to the hashmap is `count + 1` since `count` is incremented beforehand.

Of course you want the pre-increment in this case. Your problem is that you are never inserting a value into the hashmap greater the value of `1` from the initial insertion since you are doing post-increment.

But honestly, it's unnecessary to update `count` at all since it's just a temporary variable for the value in the hashmap. Instead, it would be clearer to just have

```
repeatedElementMap.put(inputArr[i], count + 1);
```